# Debugar o envio de email - java-mail-1.4.4

Tags: java, javamail

Tenho seguinte código:

```
private static boolean envioTest(final String descricao, final String msg, final String to)throws MessagingException{
    final Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "64.233.186.108");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

    final Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(user,ps);
        }
    });

    try {
        final ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        final PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(os);

        session.setDebug(true);
        session.setDebugOut(ps);
        final Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse(to));
        message.setSubject(descricao);
        message.setText(msg);
        System.out.println("Enviando....");
        Transport.send(message);

        ps.println(); // Deveria imprimir?
        return true;
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw e;
    }finally {
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
}
```

Gostaria de saber como faço para que ele imprima as informações de envio???

Na verdade não sei o que fazer com o `PrintStream`.

Tentei um `ps.println();` mas ele não exibe nada.

Obrigado!

Comment: Verifica se com System.setOut(ps) é impresso no console.

Comment: Não... e ainda não exibe o **System.out.println()** seguintes

Comment: Blz. Vou ver se acho algo e te aviso.

Comment: Informações de envio? Pode deixar mais especifico, quais informações de envio?

Comment: Qquando seto  **session.setDebug(true);** ele registra alguns logs no **PrintStream**. Não consigo imprimir o que ele grava neste **PrintStream**

Comment: Não entendi direito, você quer imprimir o conteúdo do ps?

Comment: exatamente.....

Comment: Esse `println()` vai só botar uma separação de linhas na linha atual, terminando a linha, pra imprimir o conteúdo faça `os.toString()`, não?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refletindo sobre os comentários, cheguei a seguinte conclusão:

Ele precisa de um `PrintStream` certo?

E porque criar um? Se já possuo o `System.out`?

Então ao invés de criar um novo, uso o que já possuo:

```
try {
        session.setDebug(true);
        session.setDebugOut(System.out);

      final Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse(to));
        message.setSubject(descricao);
        message.setText(msg);
        System.out.println("Enviando....");
        Transport.send(message);

        return true;
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw e;
    }finally {
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
```

E assim funcionou perfeitamente!